# What's the difference between `percona` and `percona/percona-server` docker images?

Tags: docker, percona

There're two docker images:
https://hub.docker.com/_/percona/ and https://hub.docker.com/r/percona/percona-server
Both seem to be maintained by Percona and have links to Percona's github.

Why are there two of them?
What is the difference between them?
Are they compatible with each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR - Nothing, they both are built from the [same repository](https://github.com/percona/percona-docker). However, the _/percona images are newer.**

The [official percona image](https://hub.docker.com/_/percona) was last built 4 hours ago (as of writing this), and contains this link to the maintainer's repository:

[image: Percona Official Image]

Notice the hyperlink "Maintained by: Percona", which points to this repository:

- https://github.com/percona/percona-docker

The [Percona Server image] was last built two months ago, and the description contains the following reference to the source code:

[image: Percona Server Image Description]

This link is the same as the other image, but specifically references a certain directory (which apparently no longer exists, since it returns a 404 Not Found error).

Comment: I have noticed that `_/percona` is currently out of date, at least for 5.7.x.  The latest minor release there is 5.7.35.  `r/percona/percona-server`, on the other hand, has 5.7.38.